# Android Material Edit Text endIcon

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I've added an EditText view from Google's material library and set the endIcon mode to `clear_text`. However, the endIcon is too big (it fits the text view entirely), whereas, from looking at the documentation, I believe it should be a little smaller. I tried to play around with the layout XML but can't seem to find out why this is. I've also looked at the endIcon attributes in the Material repository and there seems to be no endIconSize attribute. I'd appreciate it if someone could point out where I made the mistake.

[image: Icon size]

TextView XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/descriptionTextField"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorSecondaryLight"
app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
app:endIconMode="clear_text"
app:errorEnabled="false"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/taskConfirmedBtn"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/taskConfirmedBtn"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/taskConfirmedBtn">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
  android:id="@+id/descriptionInput"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
  android:inputType="textCapSentences"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="@color/colorOnSurface" />
```

Styles xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>

<item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>

<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.Toolbar</item>
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.ActionBar</item>
<item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.FloatingActionButton</item>
<item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.ImageButton</item>
<item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.CardView</item>
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/CustomBottomSheetDialog</item>

<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/SanSerifLightTextView</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/SansSerifLightButton</item>
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/SansSerifLightButton</item>

</style>

<!-- Themes -->

<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_bitmap</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Widgets -->

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.ActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
<item name="android:iconTint">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
<item name="tint">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.CardView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
<item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/colorSurface</item>
<item name="cardElevation">10dp</item>
<item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="DividerStyle">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.ImageButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
<item name="tint">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>

<!-- Components -->

<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
<item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
<item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorSurface</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
<item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
<item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
<item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
<item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
<item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
</style>

<!-- Fonts -->

<style name="SanSerifLightTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="SansSerifLightButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="SansSerifLightRadioButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post a screen?

Comment: And also which version are you using of material components library?

Comment: You can find the screen in the original post. I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06

Comment: First step is to migrate to the stable `1.1.0` and check again if the issue is still there

Comment: I've migrated to 1.1.0, issue is still there

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Are you using a MaterialComponents theme in your app theme?

Comment: Yes. I will include my styles xml in the original question too.

Comment: Found the issue in your style. Check che answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Taskeroo.ImageButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Taskeroo.ImageButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="tint">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

You are using `Widget.AppCompat.Button.*` instead of `Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton`.

The style `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored` has a custom dimens.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That fixed it. Grazie mille!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/customDrawable"> 
    ...
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

where custom drawable, is a vector/png image of any shape and size you will define.

If this still doesn't solve your problem, try downgrading to :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**Most probably it will solve your problem.**

Comment: I have tried using a custom vector asset and changing the size, but it always fits the view entirely. Something seems to be expanding the asset

Comment: Hi, have you tried degrading the library version..?

Comment: I have degraded to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

try this-->
Add dependency:
Gradle:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
  ...
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.4.3'
```

Use app:endIcon in xml or setEndIcon(Int resourceID) to set the icon of the ImageButton that is shown at the end of the field if you want there to be one.

```
<studio.carbonylgroup.textfieldboxes.TextFieldBoxes
...
app:endIcon="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
>
```

in java:

```
final TextFieldBoxes textFieldBoxes = findViewById(R.id.text_field_boxes);
textFieldBoxes.getEndIconImageButton().setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // What you want to do when it's clicked
}
});
```

Comment: I would prefer to stick to the Material library (my theme, widget, and styles are all Material-based)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution in `your_view.xml`

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/show_password_selector" <-- add this line
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle" <-- add this line
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"> <-- add this line

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

You can also use this solution for the start icon

**I hope help**